# Is there a way to create a list of existing fonts from an existing excel file?

Tags: c#, openxml

If the existing excel worksheet has a list of fonts with the associated name and size, is there a way to generate a list to see if the font and size already exist before adding a new font/size?

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbH3D.jpg)

When adding content via open XML, is it right to want to see if fonts (name/size) exist or simply just add another `fontID` to the list?

Comment: what is the problem actually, are you able to traverse existing fonts?

Comment: No, I am not able to traverse the existing fonts.   Its not clear to me how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

To get all available fonts in the document you can use following snippet

```
        var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"test.xlsx", true);
        var styles = doc.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart;
        var stylesheet = styles.Stylesheet;
        var availableFonts = stylesheet.Fonts.Cast<Font>();
        foreach (var font in availableFonts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Font name: {font.FontName.Val}, font size: {font.FontSize.Val}");
        }
```

If you want to check existence and add if it is not there you can use following

```
        if (!availableFonts.Any(font => font.FontSize.Val == 20 && font.FontName.Val == "Comic Sans MS"))
        {
            var font = new Font();
            font.Append(new FontSize(){ Val = 20 });
            font.Append(new FontName(){ Val = "Comic Sans MS"});
            stylesheet.Fonts.Append(font);
        }
```

Sidenote:
To apply this font to a cell you need to create CellFormat (`stylesheet.CellFormats`) and fill FontId. You refer to font using its index in `stylesheet.Fonts`. To apply CellFormat to a cell you need to set StyleIndex, you refer to index of created CellFormat in `stylesheet.CellFormats`. Something along this line

```
        stylesheet.CellFormats.Append(new CellFormat()
        {
            FontId = 1
        });
        var worksheetPart = doc.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
        var firstCell = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().First();
        firstCell.StyleIndex = 1;
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.  I was continually adding the same fonts, and borders every time I added to the spreadsheet.  Was not able to figure out how to check/add. 
 Thank you

Comment: If finding the ID of the font that matches, would the below be the best approach:   foreach (var font in availableFonts)
            {
                if (font.FontName.Val == FontName && font.FontSize.Val == fontSize)
                {
                    fontID = ii;
                    break;
                }
                ii++;
            }